# Create desktop entry to connect with ssh using terminal, warn when close window

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal

First of all I believe that gnome-terminal is very similar to mate-terminal so a solution for either these 2 will work. The proglem is that I have created a desktop entry to connect with ssh to my server as shown below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SSH
Comment=Connect to server
Exec=mate-terminal -e "ssh -X lich@192.168.2.222"
Terminal=false
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
```

But when I close the window I get no warning even if there is a command that is being executed. So I change the `Exec` line as this:

```
Exec=mate-terminal -x bash -c "ssh -X lich@192.168.2.222"
```

But I still get no warning when I close the terminal window. How can I get a warning like this:
[image]

Comment: `bash -c` is clever enough to replace itself with the single command as its argument, hence your two examples are essentially the same. Try to trick `bash -c` into not being able to exit prior to ssh's completion, e.g. `bash -c "ssh -X user@host; true"`. Not sure if it works, but worth a try.

Comment: @egmont It didn't work. I think that the `;` character waits the command to exit before the next command is executed, so `true` will be executed after I exit the ssh connection.

Comment: Yes that's why I though it would work: there are two processes, a parent bash and a child ssh (as opposed to your previous examples where bash quits and only ssh remains). Nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I added the `-i` option after bash as this:

```
Exec=mate-terminal -x bash -i -c "ssh -X lich@192.168.2.222"
```

and the problem solved.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Even with bash -i -c "ssh my.server" the terminal doesn't warn on close.

Answer (score 0):

I try this command to solved the issue.

```
Exec=mate-terminal -e "bash -i  -c 'ssh -X lich@192.168.2.222';bash"
```