# Enable close window warning for gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

When I run a command in gnome-terminal to install a critical software using sudo priviliges, for example `sudo apt install blender` and I accidentally close the window by pressing the close button, I want a pop up warning message asking for confirmation. How do I add this funtionality?

I tried using [gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/a/1433837/114437) but did not succeed. Changing [desktop entry for gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815711/create-desktop-entry-to-connect-with-ssh-using-terminal-warn-when-close-window)
 might be a solution. However i do not have the mileage and confidence to carry out this. So I need help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. When a process is ongoing, a prompt appears when I want to close either clicking the close button or hitting Alt+F4. Indicate your Ubuntu version.